# Bubble sort in R

Tags: r, sorting

How can I perform bubble sort using R and what R feature and/or packages will I be using? I have successfully performed merge sort but bubble sort cant seem to work correctly.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add a lot more details to your question. What do you mean with can't seem to work correctly? What have you tried? Where does it fail?

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like how you do it with other Sorts:

```
bubble_sort = function(array) {
    count = 0
    while(1) {
        count_swaps = 0
        for (j in 1 : (length(array) - 1 - count)) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                s = array[j]
                array[j] = array[j+1]
                array[j+1] = s
                count_swaps = count_swaps + 1
            }
        }
        count = count + 1
        if(count_swaps == 0) break
    }
    array
}
```

regards.