# Bubble sort using for loop in R

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting

I'm learning basic algorithms in R. I want to create bubble sort algorithm using for loop.

```
x <- c(20,31,8,46,19) 
for (i in 1:length(x)){

  if (x[i] > x[i+1]){
    temp <- x[i]
    x[i] <- x[i+1]
    x[i+1] <- temp
    cat(x[i],"")
   }
  else   cat (x[i],"")
}
```

I think in this particular vector, sorting should take place in three "turns.

1st should give a result: 20 8 31 19 46

2nd: 8 20 19 31 46

3rd: 8 19 20 31 46 (correct one)

This loop works out the 1st turn, **except printing the last element.**

I also don't know how to work out those other "turns". I predict it's something about the other for loop, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Some references to implement bubble sort in R. [Bubble sort in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671012/bubble-sort-in-r) and [Bubble sort using R language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051165/bubble-sort-using-r-language)

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating until the last element in `x`, but use `x[i] > x[i+1]`. So, in the last iteration `x[x+1]` is out of bounds. Look into this code which just deals with `length(x)-1` iterations plus adds an outside loop which runs from the back to the front of the vector.

```
bubblesort <- function(x) {
  for (j in (length(x)-1):1) {
    for (i in j:(length(x)-1)) {
      if (x[i] > x[i+1]) {
        temp <- x[i]
        x[i] <- x[i+1]
        x[i+1] <- temp
      }
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

x <- c(20,31,8,46,19)
print(x)
print(bubblesort(x))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using function?